# using function strpos in PHP

Tags: php

I need to create a function in PHP that can read and save in a variable two characters that are (@) and (A) of my txt file, this is my txt:

```
Trying 192.168.25.200...
Connected to 192.168.25.200.
Escape character is '^]'.
*HELLO*^@^A
```

my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['estado'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/estado.sh');
}

if(isset($_POST['ligar'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/liga.sh');
}

if(isset($_POST['desligar'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/desliga.sh');
}

echo "<H3>CONTROLE DE ILUMINACAO</H3>";

$str = file_get_contents("/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/estado.txt");
$word = "/@/";
if(strpos($str, $word) !== true) {
echo "ligado";
echo "$str";
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>
<center><input type="submit" value="Ligar" name="ligar""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="desligar" name="desligar""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="atualizar" name="estado""';" /></center>


</p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: use trim() if(strpos(trim($str), $word) !== true) {

Comment: As it is not a regexp - there's no need for slashes: `$word = "@";`

Comment: That did not work, it seems that the txt is not being sent to the variable or the comparison does not work

Answer (score 0):

According to reference strpos function returns the position of in haystack string or FALSE if the needle was not found.

You **(comparison strpos($str, $word) !== true)** is not correct. 
You must write **strpos($str, $word) === FALSE**